# Is it possible to integrate Google Earth in C# desktop application?

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, integration

For a C# desktop application I'm working on, i need (detailed / high resolution) air pictures.
I know we have Google Maps and Google Earth and some other services, and some show air images of very good resolution nowadays.
At the same time, I do not only need the images, but I need to control the zoom/rotation, and want some mechanism to measure distances in the imagery.
So what I need, is some air images API.

After some reaserch for data sources, I think the best options to get air imagery are:

- Google Maps API
- The downloadable desktop application Google Earth.

There are so many 'versions' of Google Maps / Google Earth. Some web based, some as a downloadable application.
I came to the conclusion that if I need the Google Maps API, and want an API key, I have to provide credit card information (even within the free quota). In the past you could get a free api key without providing credit card information. I don't have a credit card, and since it's not a commercial app I'm working on, it's going too far for me to apply for a credit card just for having access to the free quota of the API. It's a pity.

I managed to add a ChromiumWebBrowser control into my app, and embedded Google Maps in it. This means I embedded a webbrowser in my application, and loaded Google Maps into it like you would do when you just browse to maps.google.com. I could try to manipulate the javascript in my embedded webbrowser to control the maps app that's running in it, but this seems to be complex and cumbersome.

Another solution could be to use the downloadable Google Earth, if there's a plugin or something that can be controlled by my own code. This probably means Google Earth has to be installed on the computer, but that's OK.

So my goal is:

- Get air pictures (with highest quality available from any source).
- Creating an account/api key at some service and use some free plan is no problem, but credit card hassle to achieve this, is a problem.
- Being able to not only get the imagery but also control it. Because just getting imagery can be achieved by the workaround (embed Google Maps in a webbrowser control, and hooking the webbrowser rendering).

Anyone who has experience with this, or what are the best options?
Especially if there are options to implement Google Earth into my own desktop application, and be able to control it.

Comment: Google doesn't want to give anything away for free.  So they disabled connections that are made using software (like c#) without a key.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options here. You can use:

- [Cesium](https://cesium.com/cesiumjs/cesium-viewer/index.html?)
- [D3.js](https://d3js.org/)
- [Kartograph](http://kartograph.org/)

If you want to go the Google Maps API route, you would have to call and process the requests by hand. You can use the C# [WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class?redirectedfrom=MSDN) class to do this. You should read the documentation for the [Google Maps Platform API](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/), and you should be to send GET and POST requests with the [WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class?redirectedfrom=MSDN) class.